# .NET MVC Controller Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-mvc-controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateUser(UserCreateDTO dto)
    {
        Entity.User Us = new User();
        Us.Name = dto.Name;
        Us.Surname = dto.Surname;
        Us.Username = dto.Username;
        Us.Password = dto.Password;
        container.Users.Add(Us);
        container.SaveChanges();
        UserCreateList UsList = new UserCreateList
        {
            Id = Us.Id,
            Name = Us.Name,
            Surname = Us.Surname,
            Username = Us.Username,
            Email = Us.Email,
            Password = Us.Password
        };
        return Json(UsList);  
    }
```

It's an ajax New Member Form.
When it comes to this controller from ajax submit, it's throwing an internal network server error. I debugged the code and its crashed at the line `container.users.add(us);` and the line below..

According to my examples it must be `Users.AddObject` but there's no AddObject selection..

It can be a problem for giving error or how can I fix it.

www.muratkamci.com/exception.jpg

This is the pic of ex.

Comment: Looks to me like it's an Entity Framework exception, not an MVC exception. Put the exception details in your question.

Comment: !) What is container and where is it getting initialized? 2) What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: I would also recommend separating the command (saving the entity) and the query (returning json). instead use the post-redirect-get convention to handle this. the first action saves the entity and redirects to another action. this action queries the database and returns an json object

Comment: @Becuzz container is initializing top of the controller like that;    

private readonly UrgentquestionsContainer container;
        public HomeController()
        {
            container = new UrgentquestionsContainer();
        }

The exception's picture link is in the question. TY

Comment: @MuratKamçı You left a picture of the exception, which says to see the inner exception for details. You didn't include the inner exception details, which are necessary to see the actual problem.

Comment: @Tyrsius Here it is
http://www.muratkamci.com/exception2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

That error `"conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."` can occur when you fail to set a datetime value on a field that does not accept nulls. Since you aren't defining any `DateTime` properties on your User object, this is a likely scenario. Look at your model, and see if you can find a non-nullable datetime field.